# How do I add constraints to image resizing code? i.e. no larger than 165x146

Tags: vb.net, image-resizing

How do I add constraints to image resizing code? I want the image to be no larger then 165x146. The below code does not hold the constraint when image is 525x610

```
        intWidth = 165 '*** Fix Width ***'  
        intHeight = 146 '*** Fix Width ***' 

            If objGraphic.Width > intWidth Then
                Dim ratio As Double = objGraphic.Height / objGraphic.Width
                intHeight = ratio * intWidth
                objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic, intWidth, intHeight)
            ElseIf objGraphic.Height > intHeight Then
                Dim ratio As Double = objGraphic.Width / objGraphic.Height
                intWidth = ratio * intHeight
                objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic, intWidth, intHeight)
            Else
                objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic)
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to maintain the aspect ratio of your image? If so, this method might be appropriate; you will need to multiply the width and height by the ratio you obtain.

```
'define max size of image
intWidth = 165
intHeight = 146

'if the width/height is larger than the max, determine the appropriate ratio
Dim widthRatio as Double = Math.Min(1, intWidth / objGraphic.Width)
Dim heightRatio as Double = Math.Min(1, intHeight / objGraphic.Height)

'take the smaller of the two ratios as the one we will use to resize the image
Dim ratio as Double = Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio)

'apply the ratio to both the width and the height to ensure the aspect is maintained
objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic, CInt(objGraphic.Width * ratio), CInt(objGraphic.Height * ratio))
```

*Edit*: Probably need to explicitly convert new height and width to ints

Comment: That would return 525x610 because the ratio would be 1.

Comment: if `objGraphic.Width > intWidth`, `intWidth / objGraphic.Width` will always be < 1. Same with height. And since we perform `Min(1, [some number less than or equal to 1])`, it will be less than or equal to 1.

Comment: In your example, `widthRatio = MIN(1, 0.314) = 0.314`, `heightRatio = MIN(1, 0.239) = 0.239`, and `ratio = MIN(0.314, 0.239) = 0.239`. Your new width would be `525 * .239 = 125` and your height would be `610 * .239 = 146`

Comment: What is the reason for `ratio = MIN(0.314, 0.239) = 0.239` Why not select `ratio = MAX(0.314, 0.239) = 0.239`?

Comment: Did you mean `MAX(0.314, 0.239) = 0.314`? That would be incorrect regardless... You want it to be constrained to the max size of 165*146. You have the ratios of the original dimensions to their respective dimensions. If you chose the larger ratio (widthRatio), the new width would be exactly 165 but the new height would be larger than 146. Therefore, to constrain to your max size AND maintain the aspect ratio of the image, you must use the smaller ratio. I use similar code in many applications that handle images. My suggestion would be to step through it and test it out.